# How to switch the HDMI signal source from discrete graphics card to integrated graphics card?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, uac

I have a HP OMEN laptop with dual graphics cards inside (Intel HD 630 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, drivers up-to-date). My laptop suffers from a wired mouse-lagging problem when the windows 10 UAC prompts out, and the problem can be solved by disabling the NVIDIA graphics card from windows device manager. However this solution comes with a cost: my HDMI port can no longer output signals.

Currently I don`t use my NVIDIA graphics card very much, and I really wish to switch it off to make the UAC prompt smoother. However I do need to connect my laptop to a second screen, and is it possible to switch the HDMI signal source to the Intel graphics card?

Comment: In all likelihood, the connector is hard-wired to the GPU. Nothing can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Go to bios, there will be an option to use integraed graphics. According to internet pictures, it is in configuration. Shut down your laptop, when powering on spam f2, escape, delete keys or whatever screen says to enter bios. If you can't by those, spam f12 on next time you try, it should open a menu and then select bios. Note: bios and uefi is basically the same.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems that my laptop`s BIOS does not have a switch to turn discrete graphics card off.

Comment: @zhouyh If you looked everywhere, then probally the 1050 is the internal graphics and the disabled nvidia graphics card probally changed it from the device manager to windows generic driver or some downgraded version of 1050.

Comment: Is your BIOS up-to-date?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the solution you wanted, but have you tried the `do not dim my desktop option` for UAC? You may search for `User Account Control Settings` in the Start Menu to bring up the setting screen.

[Image: User Account Control Settings options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5QST.png)